# Dollar price of PYRO on Coinbase has risen 400% but relative swap rate for ETH on Uniswap remains the same - why?

Tags: ether, uniswap, coinbase, cryptoeconomics

I swapped ETH for PYRO when the Australian dollar (AUD) price of PYRO  was showing as around $0.00008 on Coinbase. The AUD price of Ether was around $2314 (AUD), so I swapped 0.04 ETH for 1,157,000 PYRO. In other words, the ETH 'price' I paid for PYRO was what was showing on Coinbase ($0.00008 AUD).

The Australian Dollar cost of PYRO on Coinbase later increased sharply, and showed as $0.00040 (500% of my original purchase cost). When I previewed a swap from PYRO back to ETH around 90 minutes after this price rise first showed on Coinbase, it's shows that I would get 0.036 (actually *less* than my original ETH purchase cost). Why is this? I would expect to be able to swap for around 500% of my original ETH purchase cost, i.e. 0.2 ETH.

**UPDATE**

The Etherscan page (filtered for me as a token holder), and showing details of the PYRO token contract address (0x14409b0fc5c7f87b5dad20754fe22d29a3de8217) is here - (https://etherscan.io/token/0x14409b0fc5c7f87b5dad20754fe22d29a3de8217?a=0xf8e3c5b22db3d1b1b6aaee35440eff1981fcb53e). This shows my current holding, correctly reflects the price rise of my holding (actually around 800% at the time I'm writing this). It shows that my holding is now valued at 0.33 ETH, but this still isn't reflected on Uniswap

Comment: They are two separate exchanges in an ideal world their prices will update immediately but it doesn't happen like that in the real world. Sometimes a market doesn't have enough participants, arbitrage bots that take advantage of the price difference are inactive.

Comment: Thanks @Ismael that's very helpful

Comment: I'm wondering about the downvote. Is this site meant to be only for questions about crypto mechanisms, technical details etc? So are a questions about trading considered off topic?

Comment: @Ismael, could you please explain what you mean by 'Sometimes .... arbitrage bots that take advantage of the price difference are inactive'. My understanding of arbitrage bots is that they'll take advantage of price differences across *different exchanges*. So why would arbitrage bots being inactive stop the price on Uniswap from being updated to be the same as Coinbase? Wouldn't the actions of arbitrage *cause* the prices to *converge* i.e. basic economic arbitrage theory? After 14 hours, Uniswap is still reflecting the much lower Pyro price compared to Coinbase.

Comment: Price on uniswap is updated by trade operations, if there are no operations it will not update. Arbitrage bots may stop for technical reasons, running out of funds, trading other pairs, don't be aware of pyro, they don't like pyro, fees too high, trading not worth enough, etc. Why didn't you operate if you think it is a good opportunity?

Comment: Thanks @Ismael. I made a very small swap on Uniswap from Pyro to ETH (1 Pyro), to try to trigger the price update, but it didn't update on Uniswap. The price  is still the same low price for Pyro. Is this what you meant I should do to trigger the price to update?